# iPad grayed out in Instruments target selection

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, instruments

I'm trying to profile an iPad app in Instruments, but regardsless of which profiling settings I choose, I cannot select the iPad as the profiling target:

[image]

If I hover the mouse on "Attach to Process", the only thing I see are grayed out entries for "Application" and "System".

**Any hints on the reason why I cannot use Instruments on the iPad?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that:

- You're using the latest *stable* Xcode 4.5.x (or newer) since you're targeting the latest iOS stable release;
- Instruments was started by Xcode, e.g. an old Instruments (from Xcode 4.2) can be started independently (e.g. by spotlight) and might not support iOS 6.0.1. In doubt check Instruments version;
- Your device is configured for development (look at it inside Xcode organizer, devices);
- Your device's provisioning profiles and developer's identity/certificate are up to date;

Note: you should edit your question and add the XCode version number you're using.

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed an old version of Instruments.